# PHP Laravel - link external Javascript and CSS file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel-7

I am encountering problems when trying to include the jQuery date/time picker in my appointment booking system. I have followed the Laravel convention as best I could and seem to still have no luck.

File path for css file: `public/css/file_is_here`

File path for js: `public/js/files_are_here`

A snippet of the code I tried to reference the files is below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css') }}"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    step: 30
});</script>
```

The input field is also shown:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

[image]

**Discovered weird bug whenever the page loads in the calendar will display for a second before disappearing. Could this be due to some other js, jquery or css loading in? **

Comment: As [described in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset), the `asset()` helper already generates a URL, no need for `URL::()`.  Have you checked in your rendered source what is generated?  Do you have an `ASSET_URL` value in your `.env`?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's devtools to see what is happening?  The network tab will show you if the JS files are being found and loaded correctly.  The console tab will show you if there are any JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assets are typically kept in packages.  If you are in public/css and public/js then you can treat "public" like a webroot.

src="/js/jquery.js"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually did treat it first like a normal webroot but the js/css still isnt linking in correctly. The input field is just displayed as a usual input field.

Comment: Just after finding a weird bug, whenever the page loads in and I instantly click the box it displays the calendar but after a second it disappears. Could this do with some other js or css loading in or?

Comment: Does `<script src="{{url('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>` help? Else can you show error in browser console?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't keep an eye on this yesterday.  I've never found fqdn's useful unless I'm linking off-site.  In-site I've always used used links relative to the root by starting with a slash.  Anyway, this definitely sounds like a js issue - but start a new question for that.  Abandon or delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="{{ asset('public/plugins/datetime/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('public/plugins/datetime/jquery.datetimepicker.css') }}" />
```

it's work with me